# Binary serial port reading messes up data sometimes

Tags: serial-port, communication

I have a serial port. The other program writes to the serial port in every 0.2 second. Each time, the data written to the serial port is always 83 bytes in length. The serial port can be read correctly using minicom.

I have a program that can read the serial port. Each time, the byte stream written to the serial port is:

65 66 67 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90

Most of the times the data can be received correctly. However, sometimes the data is messed up. Once the data is messed up, almost all the incoming messages are messed up.

Sometimes, I get output from my code as:

65 0 66 67 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90 65 66 67

This is weird. Since apparently, there is a 0 after the first 65. Also, the last three bytes is 65 66 67, which looks like is the begging of a new message.

The code for opening and configurating the serial port is:

```
int serial_fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY|O_NONBLOCK);
if (serial_fd < 0) {
    return -1;
}

struct termios options;
tcgetattr(serial_fd, &options);
options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
//8N1 mode
options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
options.c_cflag |= CS8;
options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
options.c_cflag &=~PARENB;
options.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;

options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO|ECHONL|ISIG|IEXTEN); 
options.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL|IXON);
options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;  
cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
tcsetattr(serial_fd, TCSANOW, &options);
tcflush(serial_fd, TCIFLUSH);
```

The code for reading from the serial port and printing out the received message is:

```
uint8_t *buff,buff_data[100];
buff = buff_data;
int len,fs_sel;
fd_set fs_read;

int expectedLength=83;
int len_acc = 0;

while(1){
    FD_ZERO(&fs_read); 
    FD_SET(serial_fd, &fs_read);
    fs_sel = select(serial_fd+1,&fs_read,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    if(fs_sel)   
    {
        len = read(serial_fd, buff, expectedLength-len_acc);
        if (len<=0) continue;
        len_acc += len;
        if (len_acc < expectedLength) {
            buff += len;
            continue;
        }
        len_acc = 0;
        buff = buff_data;
        for (int i=0; i<expectedLength; i++){
            std::cout <<(int)buff[i]<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The occurrence of the additional null byte can be caused by a framing error, parity error, or a break condition.  This inserted byte can be inhibited, but your termios configuration does not.  BTW solely counting bytes is not a reliable method of delimiting messages.

Comment: Thank you, sawdust. How can I configure the termios to inhibit the additional null byte? In serial port communication, what is the reliable way to delimit messages? If we use specific codes to mark the beginning and end of a message, framing errors/parity errors can still happen. In our application scenarios, timing is critical and we cannot request the sender to send the message again if we detect the message is messed up. If we reduce the message length to one byte, do we expect the framing errors/parity errors to reduce? Thanks.

Comment: If IGNPAR is set, then framing and parity errors are ignored. If IGNBRK is set, then a break condition is ignored.  Your program clears IGNBRK, and leaves IGNPAR in an unknown state.  But you might want to determine which condition is happening, and why, and maybe even try to eliminate it.  Typical serial protocols for robust communications employ verification of message length using start and stop bytes, and content verification using checksum or CRC.  At the very least you only want to process valid messages.  If it's bad in any way, then you have to discard it.

Comment: Thank you. I will try what you suggest and figure out what causes the problem.